# ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: math-mode, cases

I got this problem in following code:

```
$X = \begin{cases}
x_{1} & if & u \in [0,p_{1}] \\
x_{2} & if & u \in [p_{1},p_{1} + p_{2}] \\
\dots \\
x_{j} & if & u \in [\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}p_{k}, \sum_{k=1}^{j}p_{k}] \\
\end{cases}$
```

Hope someone can help, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

A `cases` environment only has two columns, so use something like this instead. You probably want to use displayed math for this as well, and not inline math, so I changed from `$ .. $` to `\[ .. \]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
X = \begin{cases}
x_{1} & \text{if } u \in [0,p_{1}] \\
x_{2} & \text{if } u \in [p_{1},p_{1} + p_{2}] \\
\dots \\
x_{j} & \text{if } u \in [\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}p_{k}, \sum_{k=1}^{j}p_{k}] \\
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

or with `cases*` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
X = \begin{cases*}
x_{1} & if $u \in [0,p_{1}]$ \\
x_{2} & if $u \in [p_{1},p_{1} + p_{2}]$ \\
\,\vdots \\
x_{j} & if $u \in \left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^{j-1}p_{k}, \sum\limits_{k=1}^{j}p_{k}\right]$ \\
\end{cases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]